# How do I position tkinter widgets under an existing widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I was recently introduced to tkinter, and I'm attempting to write a calculator application to become familiar with it. The `Entry` widget where the input goes, which I call the "display" seems to be pushing the `Button` widgets to the right. My question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485408/how-to-pack-a-tkinter-widget-underneath-an-existing-widget-that-has-been-packed), however all of the answers there involve the `pack()` method while I'm only trying to use the `grid()` method for my layout. How can I position the `Button` widgets so that they are directly under the `Entry` widget rather than being pushed off to the right? Here's the current code for my application:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

button = list()
numbers = ("789456123")

def create_number_buttons():
    i = 0
    for row in range(1, 4):
        for column in range(1, 4):
            button.append(tk.Button(root, text=numbers[i], padx=10, pady=10))
            button[i].grid(row=row, column=column, padx=1, pady=1)
            i += 1

display = tk.Entry(root, width=25)
display.grid(row=0, column=0)
create_number_buttons()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just have to add "columnspan=4" as an parameter to display grid something like this

```
display.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)
```

by default value of columnspan is set to 1

rest of your code seems OK :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `columnspan` key word argument to the geometry manager of display:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

button = list()
numbers = ("789456123")

def create_number_buttons():
    i = 0
    for row in range(1, 4):
        for column in range(1, 4):
            button.append(tk.Button(root, text=numbers[i], padx=10, pady=10))
            button[i].grid(row=row, column=column, padx=1, pady=1)
            i += 1

display = tk.Entry(root)
display.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)
create_number_buttons()

root.mainloop()
```